# Does a Barbarian's Fast Movement affect non-walking speeds?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, barbarian

So a baseline Barbarian in D&D 5e gets Fast Movement at 5th level (Player's Handbook, p. 49):

> your speed increases by 10 feet while you aren't wearing heavy armor.

The Storm Herald Barbarian subclass gets a feature at 6th level that *can* grant you a new, non-walking, movement speed if you pick the Sea environment ability (Xanathar's Guide to Everything, p. 10, emphasis mine):

> *Sea* You gain resistance to lightning damage, and you can breathe underwater. **You also gain a swimming speed of 30 feet**.

Does the Fast Movement feature interact with this swim speed for an overall swimming speed of 40 feet?

Does Fast Movement *in general* interact with non-walking speeds? If so, would it apply to a swim or climb speed granted through a different method, like a spell or magic item?

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe, because while the other question uses different examples, the end question is the same. If there's some aspect I missed which means the target Q does not resolve this, please point it out and we'll see what needs to be done.

Comment: Fair enough! I was focusing v tightly on the class and missed the other Q. Should I delete this?

Comment: No, this question will be helpful for the next person who's looking at this feature and will help them find the question where it's answered. Dupes in general are useful for this reason, even if it might be slightly counter-intuitive to start with :)